# Conditional DataTemplate for Images

Tags: wpf, xaml

Trying to use the same control for displaying a column with images and without, depending on a boolean (HistoryOn). Next xaml code works, but always shows the images.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumnx:Name="dgtc">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding 
                 Converter={StaticResource myDataRowToListConverter}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                          <Border x:Name="imageBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"                                
                                  MouseLeave="imageBorder_MouseLeave"
                                  MouseEnter="imageBorder_MouseEnter"Height="16">
                             <Image x:Name="myImage" Source="{BindingMyImagePath}"
                                MouseUp="Image_MouseUp" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            </Image>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Next xaml code displays only the path, not the images. What is wrong?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="dgtc">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding  
                Converter={StaticResource myDataRowToListConverter}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyImagePath}">
                            <ContentControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HistoryOn}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                                Value="{StaticResource imagesOff}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HistoryOn}" Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                                Value="{StaticResource imagesOn}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ContentControl.Style>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In the Windows.Resources:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="imagesOn">
    <Border x:Name="imageBorder1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"                                      
            MouseLeave="imageBorder_MouseLeave"
            MouseEnter="imageBorder_MouseEnter"Height="16">
        <Image x:Name="myImage" Source="{BindingMyImagePath}"
               MouseUp="Image_MouseUp"HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        </Image>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
 <DataTemplatex:Key="imagesOff">
    <Border x:Name="imageBorder2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"                                      
            MouseLeave="imageBorder_MouseLeave"
            MouseEnter="imageBorder_MouseEnter"Height="16">
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Much simpler, use only the `imagesOn` DataTemplate directly as the ItemTemplate (as in your first XAML) and bind the Visibility property of the Image control to the HistoryOn property with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter. Or use the DataTriggers in a Style for the Image control to set its Visibility.

Comment: Would only setting the visibility avoid long waiting times? HistoryOn means that the whole history of displayed images is shown. Takes minutes...

Comment: As long as the Image control isn't visible it should not try to load the image from the bound path. Give it a try.

Comment: In fact even if Visibility = "Hidden" the images are loaded. At least I see in the Diagnostic Tools window many errors coming by that read: Exception caught: 'System.NotSupportedException' in System.dll ("ImageSourceConverter cannot convert from System.String.")

Comment: How about Visibility.Collapsed?

Comment: Visibility = "Collapsed" has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CellTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to Choose the desired template depending on the object take a look at [this link](https://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/apply-conditional-data-template-in-data-grid/) to see a detailed example on this topic
Good Luck

Comment: Great. That works fine. The crux was to find what object parameter the SelectTemplate should have. It turned out to be a DataRowView.